# How to sort selected rows in MariaDb/MySQL by costum fuction?

Tags: mysql, function, sorting, mariadb, sql-order-by

I have 100000 products and 500 categories.
every product is in 10 categories. products and categories are in many to many relation.
i want to find 10 most related products by category.

for example product

```
P1 is in 1,2,3,4,5 categories.
P2 is in 4,5,6,7,8 categories.
P3 is in 2,3,4,5,6 categories.
```

the most related product to P1 is P3.because they are common in 4 categories.
i need a query to get 10 most related product to a specific product.

is this query costly in performance?

Comment: What version are you running?  (MySQL 8.0 has extended bit operations to BLOBs; I am thinking about recommending `BIT_COUNT()` on 500-bit blobs.)

Comment: Is that an average of 2000 products in each category?

Comment: What is given?  I see one answer that assumes that you are only interested in "nearest" to product #X.

Comment: @RickJames yes i want to get nearest to priduct #x. version is 10.4.8-MariaDB. yes int this time average is 2000 products in each category but admin can change the categoriese and the products will added.

Comment: The may be some kludge that involves `JSON_MERGE_PATCH` and `JSON_LENGTH` to discover how much two json strings overlap.  The JSON values might be simply "[2,3,4,5,6]" in the `products` table.  Does someone want to take this idea and run with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query would be:

```
SELECT pother.id, count(*) as common
FROM product
JOIN category ON product.category = category.id
JOIN product pother ON pother.category = category.id
WHERE product.id = X
GROUP BY pother.id
ORDER BY common DEC LIMIT 10
```

Provided the `product.category` is indexed and you've limited a product to 10 categories it might not be too bad. There should be a optimizer path for that.

Alternate subquery form

```
SELECT id, count(*) as common
FROM product
JOIN category
  ON product.category = category.id AND category.id IN (select category FROM product WHERE product.id = X)
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY comm DESC LIMIT 10
```

Can you edit the query plan into this answer?

Comment: I'm curious, how fast is it? What does the query plan of [ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON {query}](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/analyze-format-json/) show?

Comment: great. i thought we have no solution for it but it works!! is this query costly in performance? you suggest to run this query when i need to show related product or add some columns for saving common products?

Comment: Either way. Your case is the important one.